# Visual Studio Code Java: Disable serialVersionUID warning

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, warnings, serializable

I'm taking a Computer Science class where the assignment boilerplate code is a Java framework where most of the classes (or their superclasses) extend Serializable. What ends up happening then is VSCode complains to me that

`The serializable class [insert class name here] does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long"`

for nearly all the starting code. I know in other IDEs such as IntelliJ and Eclipse, this specific warning can be suppressed for all Java projects. What would be the equivalent operation in VSCode? I have the Language Support for Java package installed.

The following are reasons why I cannot declare a serialVersionUID or use @SuppressWarnings:

1. This would force me to modify code which I am not allowed to modify. The prof only wants students to implement certain areas of the framework.
2. I would need to make these changes to about 30 classes which is less than ideal.

Comment: Why not just declare that field? :)

Comment: To declare the field, I would need to declare that for dozens of classes, and I'm not supposed to change that portion of the code. I can only change the portions that instructors want us to change.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes

Comment: IMHO the question is perfectly valid, with inlineing: new HashMap<String, String>() {{put{"a", "b"}}} this warning is raised, but you certainly do not want this

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Currently Java Support for VSCode reads a file called `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` as part of its Eclipse project support. That's a folder called `.settings` in the root folder of the project, then a file called `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` in that folder.

In this file, we can suppress the serialVersionUID warning by adding the following line:
`org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingSerialVersion=ignore`

Now just restart VS Code, and those warnings will no longer show up.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! Despite many folks arguing against your question on "best practice" or what you "should" do, sometimes we just want to know "how" to do something. Going forward, guess we can use Eclipse to configure the prefs and use those in VS Code.

Comment: Shell command to add this: `mkdir -p .settings && touch .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs && echo "org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingSerialVersion=ignore" >> .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`

Comment: Is there any extension could help us to generate serialVersionUID?

Comment: Restarting no longer seems necessary.